# MS Query - запрос LIKE

Tags: sql, excel

Имеется таблица в экселе. Столбец `name` имеет тип текст и содержит значение jane. Пытаюсь сделать запрос на `like`

```
SELECT *
FROM `Лист1$`
WHERE name like 'ja%'
```

Выскакивает окно о синтаксической ошибке. При этом, если запрос изменить на нижеприведенный, то ошибки не возникает:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Лист1$`
WHERE name='jane'
```

Помогите разобраться, почему в первом случае возникает синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: Пробовали для начала like 'jane'? Если да то попробуйте like 'ja*'

Comment: Каким средством Вы производите вызов SQL к листу?

Comment: @ReinRaus данные/из других источников/из microsoft query. там в окне есть кнопка с наименованием sql, куда можно вводить запросы

Answer (score 0):

Измените запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM `Лист1$`
WHERE name ='ja%'
```

Comment: все та же синтаксическая ошибка. кстати, если сделать просто like 'jane', то такой вариант тоже не принимается. почему-то любой запрос на like выдает синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: А так попробуйте

Comment: тоже не подходит

Comment: Последний  вариант как?